# Taking an exam in math analysis course.

Tags: real-analysis, advice

So I'm taking my first midterm exam in math analysis soon and I'm confused on how to study for it. I mean in calculus one would be able to just go into the book and take derivatives and integrals until it was second nature, but in analysis, the class is mostly proving theorems and writing proofs of important theorems. I understand that every university and even every class is going to be different but what are some of the essential things that are learned in the first part of an analysis course that would likely be tested on? If anyone is familiar with Charles Pugh's text on Real Analysis the exam covers the whole first chapter and section 1 of chapter 2.

In class we have covered openness and closedness of sets, continuity, the construction of the real number system in the method of Cauchy sequences (professor didnt really touch on them being built on cuts too much, but a little), homeomorphisms, upper and lower bounds, cardinality, etc.

Of course I'm going to study those topics, but is there a good way or a suggested way that tends to help students prepare for those in an exam?

Comment: Could you give a little more information about the material that you have covered so far, and your background in proof writing? Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamStagner Sure, I added some more in there!

Comment: Usually, and in great generality, the things you are most likely to be tested on in an exam are the things you have been tested on in your homework assignments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's what I figured. What's your take on rewriting the homework solutions? I had a tough time with the homework, so it may help? Or would another study approach be rewriting the proofs of the important theorms I found in my book?

Comment: Dear Kyle, you can try to figure out the proofs on your own, but it is even more important to do problems from other texts. For example, if you will be tested on open sets, you should try to get hold of as many problems on open sets as possible. There is an abundance of exams posted online by professors from many schools.

Comment: You are asking me questions for which you would get much better answers from the person teaching the course.

Comment: Well I'm not intentionally trying to ask what is going to be on that because of course I know that only my professor would know (I appologize if that's how it came off). What I'm mostly trying to ask is what a good study method for studying analysis would be whether it be from personal experience or perhaps you are a professor yourself that has seen what helps students study and what doesnt.

Comment: I am currently taking Analysis myself and took a test today. What I found out was know your proofs, theorems and know the concepts inside and out. and the only way you will get better at that is by doing a whole lot of practice problems and not just from your book, go online and search for some more problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the definitions.
Try to prove the theorems yourself.
If you can't , understand the proof idea and why you missed it.
Thinking visually and creating examples may help to solve the problems.